# Differential functions Probem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ to be differential functions such that

$$\text{grad }f(X)=h(X)X.$$

Show that $f$ is constant over r-sphere centered at the origin.

I have no good idea to show that.

Comment: Hint: Your condition says that the gradient is orthogonal to every $r$-sphere.

Comment: By hypothesis, The gradient is a radial application. So, let $x\in \mathcal{S}_r(0)$ and $\lambda:(-\delta,\delta)\to\mathcal{S}_r(0)$ a patch, such that $\lambda(0)=x$ and $\lambda '(0)=v$, we have that $\text{d}f_x\dot v=<\text{grad }f(x),v>=0$. Since $\mathcal{S}_r(0)$ is conex, then $f$ is constant over $\mathcal{S}_r(0)$. All right @mickep?

Comment: Not sure about your notation, but yes something like that.

Comment: But ok, thank a lot @mickep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\|x_0\| = \|x_1\|>0$ then there is a differentiable path $t \mapsto x(t)$ such that $x(0) = x_0$, $x(1) = x_1$ and $\|x(t)\| = \|x_0\|$ for all $t$.

In particular, we have $\langle Dx(t), x(t) \rangle = 0$ for all $t \in (0,1)$.

Let $\phi(t) = f(x(t))$, then $\phi'(t) = \langle \nabla f(x(t)), Dx(t) \rangle
= h(x(t)) \langle x(t), Dx(t) \rangle = 0$, and so $\phi(0) = \phi(1)$.